# Iterating over list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dfs as such:

```
ListOfDFs = [DP, SMP, SMD, MP, MD, MSM, SAP, SAD,SAMA, SAM, AP,AD, ASM, AM,ASA]
```

now I want to iterate over each dataframe to remove NaNs.

I've tried the following:

```
for i in ListOfDFs[i]:
    i = i.fillna("")

#SMP = SMP.fillna("")
#SMP
```

However with no success..

Comment: Read on how to loop through a list: https://pythonguides.com/python-loop-through-a-list/ Then you can remove NaN with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you tried

```
for i in ListOfDFs:
```

instead of

```
for i in ListOfDFs[i]:
```

The reason it doesnt work is with this line

```
    i = i.fillna("")
```

`i` was refering to each dataframe but then it refers to a new dataframe and forgets avout the previous. you use list comprehend to solve it

```
ListOfDFs = [df.fillna("") for df in ListOfDFs]
```

this way a new list with nans filled dataframes assigned back to ListOfDFs.

so the issue is not pandas specific

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However using the list comprehension method does not work unfortunately..

Comment: i=len(ListOfDFs)
for df in ListOfDFs[i]:
    ListOfDFs = [df.fillna("") for df in ListOfDFs]

Comment: ListOfDFs = [df.fillna("") for df in ListOfDFs] does not work either

Comment: It does work when calling the list but not when querying a specific dataframe from the list

Comment: @RobdeLeeuw For a specific dataframe you need `i = 3; ListOfDFs[i] = ListOfDFs[i].fillna("")` and you can change `i` as you need. this code direct changes the ith element of the list dafaframes

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-fe4a038800ff> in <module>
      1 i = 15
----> 2 ListOfDFs[i] = ListOfDFs[i].fillna("")

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @RobdeLeeuw you need to have at least 16 dataframes in your list for that to work because Python 0 indexed. how many dataframes you have there.

Answer (score 0):

since you mention

> remove NaNs

have you tried `df.dropna()` ?

see this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

you can apply it, like:

```
ListOfDFs = [DP, SMP, SMD, MP, MD, MSM, SAP, SAD,SAMA, SAM, AP,AD, ASM, AM,ASA]
    
for i in ListOfDFs[i]:   
    i.dropna() #use arguments if needed
```